# How can I execute JavaScript on the server when using the Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, clojure

I am using MongoDB with Clojure and Congomongo and I am trying to execute some basic Java-Script while inserting documents.

There are two use cases were I want to execute some Java-Script during the an insert:
a) writing a last-modifed Timestamp 
b) creating a version tag as ObjectId

Both are very similar, here are some MongoDB Shell examples.

```
db.test.update({_id:ObjectId("4fe3304fc2e61906ccdd7364")}, {$set: {created:Date()}}, false, false)
```

or

```
db.test.insert({version:ObjectId(), foo:"Bar"})
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can do it using Congomongo or the plain Java-Driver?

I tried

```
org.bson.types.Code
org.bson.types.CodeWScope
```

and got something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe32998c2e61906ccdd735f"), "version" : function cf__14_anon() { return ObjectId(); } }
```

which is interesting but not helpful. Unfortunately it's not possible to create the timestamps/version/ObjectId on the client, because I can't make sure that the clocks of the clients are synchronous. We use the `version` synchronize/replicate data between server and the clients and creating versions/timestamps in the past does jeopardize this process.

Thanks for your help in advance ....

Comment: Had a long comment here, decided to change it to "No, you can't". That said I honestly can't think of why you'd run into a problem like this. Your app servers should be time synced, why can't that be the case for you? And if you can't time sync machines how valuable is trusting the time of the mongod instance you happen to run this update on?

Comment: The value in trusting the mongod machine time is, that it will always create a monotonous increasing sequence of object IDs which I cannot guarantee if I work with multiple nodes. I just wondered, if this was easily possible, because MonogoDB is doing the exact same thing with the `_id` field (okay I', pretty sure it works differently inside of mongod).

Comment: Well if that was what happens then yes but ObjectIds are generated client side by design and it's pretty well documented that you shouldn't see ObjectIds as a time sortable type. I would make sure your app servers (or client equivalent) generate the Dates and ObjectIds and that all those instances are NPT synced.